# Can't select (by key of type map<text,text>) a record which has been inserted to Cassandra with Datastax Java driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to do some real time analytics using Cassandra counters and Datastax Java driver. The unit tests with an embedded Cassandra (version 2.1.9, provided by cassandra-unit) passed successfully however when I deployed it to real cluster (version 2.2.3) I was not able to select what was inserted.

My Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE analytics.aggregate (
    tick bigint,
    tick_type text,
    aggregate_type text,
    dimensions frozen<map<text, text>>,
    value counter,
    PRIMARY KEY ((tick, tick_type, aggregate_type, dimensions))
);
```

I'm using Datastax Java driver with driver-mapping package version 2.1.7.1. I have an accessor interface defined:

```
@Accessor
public interface CassandraWriter {

    @Query(
            "UPDATE " +
                "analytics.aggregate " +
            "SET " +
                "value = value + :value " +
            "WHERE " +
                "tick = :tick AND " +
                "tick_type = :tick_type AND " +
                "aggregate_type = :aggregate_type AND " +
                "dimensions = :dimensions"
    )
    @QueryParameters(consistency = "QUORUM")
    Statement increment(
            @Param("tick") long tick,
            @Param("tick_type") String tickType,
            @Param("aggregate_type") String aggregateType,
            @Param("dimensions") Map<String, String> dimensions,
            @Param("value") long value
    );
}
```

And use this code for insertion:

```
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement(BatchStatement.Type.COUNTER);

for (MyPojo pojo : pojos) {
    batch.add(
        cassandraWriter.increment(
            pojo.getTick(),
            pojo.getTickType(),
            pojo.getAggregateType(),
            pojo.getDimensions(),
            pojo.getValue()
        )
    );
}

session.execute(batch);
```

(yes I know using batch statements executed synchronously is not the best practice, consider this just as a PoC)

In the end I'm not able to query what was inserted. In cqlsh, when using a wildcard select statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM analytics.aggregate LIMIT 10;
```

I get the result. However when I try to select with a where clause, e. g.:

```
SELECT value 
FROM analytics.aggregate 
WHERE 
    tick=1455551820000 AND
    tick_type='MINUTE' AND
    aggregate_type='REQUEST_COUNT' AND 
    dimensions={'customer_id': '1', 'city_id': '2'};
```

I get an empty result set.

The query above works fine when I insert a record via cqlsh manually though. So there seems to be an issue on the inserting side.

Is it something related to this:

[Can't retrieve by UDT key from cassandra with datastax java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373008/cant-retrieve-by-udt-key-from-cassandra-with-datastax-java-driver)

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-831

?

Update:replying to paprika's comment. Yes I've also tried individual statements instead of batches and the result was the same, the issue is still there.

The code I used for insertion:

```
List<ResultSetFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>(pojos.size());
for (MyPojo pojo : pojos) {
    futures.add(
        session.executeAsync(
            cassandraWriter.increment(
                pojo.getTick(),
                pojo.getTickType(),
                pojo.getAggregateType(),
                pojo.getDimensions(),
                pojo.getValue()
            )
        )
    );
}

for (ResultSetFuture future : futures) {
    future.getUninterruptibly();
}
```

MyPojo is really just a pojo, there's nothing special about it:

```
public class MyPojo {

    private long tick;
    private String tickType;
    private String aggregateType;
    private Map<String, String> dimensions;
    private long value;

    public long getTick() {
        return tick;
    }

    public void setTick(long tick) {
        this.tick = tick;
    }

    public String getTickType() {
        return tickType;
    }

    public void setTickType(String tickType) {
        this.tickType = tickType;
    }

    public String getAggregateType() {
        return aggregateType;
    }

    public void setAggregateType(String aggregateType) {
        this.aggregateType = aggregateType;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDimensions() {
        return dimensions;
    }

    public void setDimensions(Map<String, String> dimensions) {
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
    }

    public long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In the meantime I also tried upgrading Datastax driver from v. 2.1.7.1 to 3.0.0 but this didn't help.

Comment: Some generic remarks:  Try to test using a single record instead of a batch to further minimize your test case.  Also, you should post the actual implementation of `MyPojo` so that it's clear what you are trying to insert.